# aspectj prevent loadtime weaving recursively

Tags: jruby, aspectj, liferay-6

To sketch to problem a little:
We are using a liferay portal solution for our websites and to add some functionality and fix bugs we are using aspects within the portal. The amount of aspects on it's own are not a problem on startup but the amount of classloaders they start weaving at times is.
Liferay uses JRuby to perform SASS evalution on CSS files. Each CSS file that gets processed gets it's own jruby classloader (my knowledge of jruby is limited so I don't know if that is the way it is supposed to work or not). This has a result that if alot of css/jruby actions get executed at the same time the memory can jump by 1.5GB and make the JVM run out of memory. If the JVM survives this initial jump or if not to many files get processed at the same time then the memory use returns to normal after a while. So the problem is clearly caused by the memory overhead from the weaving process

In trying to find a solution I came up with several changes that can be done. But I'm not sure which the better one would be and if some of the options are even possible.

1. is there a way to exclude some classloaders from getting processed by aspectj. In this case that would be the jrubyclassloader ( from what I found after searching I think that this is not possible)
2. can jruby be limited to use just 1 classloader in some way as this would reduce the weaving overhead, if this would mean that jruby can only do serial processing then that wouldn't be a problem
3. recursivly limit the classes that get weaven by aspectj (don't think exclude in aop.xml is the way to go but add a cflow limitation to each aspect individually)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that configuration in the aop.xml file is the way to go.  See https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html You will want to use the exclude option.

An example from the documentation:

```
        <weaver options="-verbose">
          <!-- Weave types that are within the javax.* or org.aspectj.*
               packages. Also weave all types in the foo package that do
               not have the @NoWeave annotation. -->
          <include within="javax.*"/>
          <include within="org.aspectj.*"/>
          <include within="(!@NoWeave foo.*) AND foo.*"/>

          <!-- Do not weave types within the "bar" pakage -->
          <exclude within="bar.*"/>

          <!-- Dump all types within the "somepack" package,
               both before are after they are woven,
               to the "./_ajdump" folder on disk (for diagnostic purposes) -->
          <dump within="somepack.*" />
        </weaver>
```

Comment: from what I understand from the documentation is that if you have 3 classes A calls B calls C and say exlude within A. Then calls to B from A will not be woven but calls from B to C will. What I would like to see is that I can say to the weaver anything after A gets ignored so both B & C

Answer (score 0):

For whom may need the answer of 1. question is, you can use `aj.weaving.loadersToSkip` parameter to skip class loader. You need to pass this parameter as vm argument.

For instance:

```
-Daj.weaving.loadersToSkip=weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader
```